# CC and CXX unchanged when using sudo

Tags: macos, terminal, sudo

This may be similar or even a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5944228/python-build-using-wrong-version-of-gcc-on-os-x) question but when I export the CC and CXX flags on my Mac OSX, anything that I try to compile only uses the c and c++ compilers specified by the export IF I do not use sudo. sudo'ing overwrites these flags to use the default clang compiler.

This may not be a problem except in cases when I need to use openmp or when I do not have root access. I tried to search for why this happens but came up empty. Is there a reason why sudo overwrites these variables?

Thank you.

Comment: `sudo` by default limits the environment variables that are propagated into child processes for security reasons. You could configure `sudo` to pass the `CC` and `CXX` flags, but there is probably a better way to do this (e.g. `root`s `.bashrc` or something).

Comment: But I can't do root if I am not root right? And I have tried everything that comes close in my .bashrc. Nothing worked. I had this problem for a long time and none of the solutions worked which is why I posted here so if a solution comes up, someone that has this problem can get help.

Also, what security issues could be there in the c compiler flags? I mean ..... it's a C compiler?

Comment: It's not so much that there are security issues specifically with `CC` or `CXX`. Rather, to avoid any number of possible things getting in, the list of environment variables that are forwarded is kept to a minimum. If you `sudo some-program`, you are running that program as `root` (unless you are doing `sudo -l some-other-user some-program`). That's the primary purpose of `sudo` - to let you run specific things as a different user, like `root`...